# Creating UpdateForm by using ModelForm in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a Django application and I wanna create an update form with ModelForm but I have to get the `fields` parameter from `user_profile` model. So I have created my form and view such as below.

forms.py;

```
class UpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = []
        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        input_choices = kwargs.pop('input_choices')
        super(UpdateForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields = input_choices
```

views.py;

```
@login_required(login_url = "user:login")
def updateData(request,id):
    features = request.user.profile.selected_features
    instance = get_object_or_404(Data,id = id)
    
    form = UpdateForm(request.POST or None, input_choices=features, instance=instance)

    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.save(commit=False)
        data.author = request.user
        data.save()
        return redirect("data:dashboard")
    return render(request,"update.html",{"form":form})
```

However, I'm getting a `list indices must be integers or slices, not str` error in the `return render(request,"update.html",{"form":form})` line. There is an issue with the `fields` parameter but I couldn't find anything.

How can I pass the `fields` parameter from view to ModelForm?

Comment: What is `features` and what is your expected input for `input_choices`? Can you add the `Data` model to your question and the result of `request.user.profile.selected_features`

Comment: As you know normally the ModelForm 'fields' contains the parameters that are in the Model. But in my app, the users selected the parameters when they registered. They can use just what they want. So my 'features' is some of my model parameters according to user selection.

Comment: The fields are completely dynamic and not fields on the `Data` model?

Comment: The fields on the Data model but not all of them, yes, it has to be dynamic. For ex; my Data model contains: name, username, phone_number, etc. but my user selected only username parameter so the Data forms should be created with just username parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`modelform_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function) to create a form with dynamic fields

```
from django.forms import modelform_factory

@login_required(login_url = "user:login")
def updateData(request,id):
    features = request.user.profile.selected_features
    instance = get_object_or_404(Data, id=id)
    UpdateForm = modelform_factory(Data, fields=features)
    form = UpdateForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
```

If `features` is a queryset, you'll probably have to use something like `features.values_list('name', flat=True)` to get just the names of the fields

Comment: I've been dealing with this for days. thank you so much, it works!